# Do input size effect mobilenet-ssd in aspect-ratio and real anchor ratio? (Tensorflow API)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, tensorflow-ssd

im recently using tensorflow api object detection. The default SSD-MobileNet v1 is using 300 x 300 images as input training image, but i gonna edit the image size as width and height in different values. For instance, 320 * 180. Are aspects ratio in .config represent the real ratio of the anchors width/height ratio or they are just for the square images?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the "size" to any different value , the general guidance is preserve the aspect ratio of the original image while the size can be different value.

Answer (score 0):

Aspect ratios represent the real ratio of anchors. You can use it for different input ratios, but you will get the best result if you use input ratio similar to square images.